# Python Recursividade - Resto da divisão de dois números

Tags: python, recursão, divisão

Estou tendo dificuldades para resolver um problema em Python usando a forma recursiva:

**Faça uma função recursiva que obtenha o resto da divisão entre dois
números inteiros positivos.** 
Exemplo: resto(33,5) = 3

Podem me ajudar por gentileza? só sei resolver o enunciado em questão, da forma tradicional

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Poderia editar a pergunta e colocar um [mcve] mostrando sua tentativa em resolver o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução:

```
def resto(n, m):
    if (n < m):
        return (n)
    else:
        return resto(n-m, m)
```